# Error on executing Http post in honeycomb

Tags: android, apache, http, post, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have two Android mobile devices one v2.3 api 9 and one v3.1 honeycomb
I want to post an http api link for sms code. It turns that i got an error in honeycomb and the other mobile works fine this is the code

```
public void sendSMS(String phone_num, int password)
{
try
{               
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com/");
    hc.execute(post); // I got an error here    
}
catch(IOException e)
{

    Log.e("error", "error");
}  
}
```

Answer (score 11):

StrictMode is enabled in HoneyComb, you must disable it to avoid [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

### **but that´s not recommended**, use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), here you can find an example:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 6):

You're experiencing this because of a new feature in Android Honeycomb.  If you look through your logs you will see you are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` Exception

In Android Honeycomb there is a new application policy **that restricts the execution of time consuming calls on the main thread**.

Please check your exception stack if you see the following: `StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork`

What helped me was to [read this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) and then fix my code to not use the main execution thread for the HTTP call.

Answer (score 5):

100% working solution!

Place the following codes above your `super.onCreate` under `protected void onCreate` method:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Idea from Jorgesys! Thanks to him! Hope it solves your problem~

Comment: From my understanding, these lines of codes allow android OS to bypass the "strictmode" restriction. As you upgrading your phone to android 3.0 (honeycomb) or android 4.0 (ICS) and above, the "thread" connection such as socket-based connections and HTTP connections are restricted under ThreadPolicy, this is because new android OS encourage connections through AsyncTask methods, and this replaced the use of "Thread" connections in future.

Therefore, with the codes above, you force the execution to ignore the the restriction through "permitAll()".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and cleared using Async Task.So dont call httppost request in main thread Instead ***use Async task to do http post***.It also gives you more comfortable .link:http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html